# Error when when running stockfish (shared-libary) in android studio

Tags: java, android, stockfish

I have compiled Stockfish 16 with CMake to and SharedLibary (.so). But when i run this libary in my code, Logcat give me the following Error:

```
2023-07-24 18:14:11.770     0-0     lib_stockfish_s[4976]   kernel                               I  segfault at 0 ip 000071fa37c9f047 sp 00007fffb509c0e0 error 6 in lib_stockfish_sixten.so[71fa37c9f000+281c000]
2023-07-24 18:14:11.773     0-0     Code                    kernel                               I  00 00 00 40 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 88 6c 82 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 40 00 38 00 0a 00 40 00 1a 00 19 00 06 00 00 00 04 00 00 <00> 40 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 40 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 40 00 00 00 00
```

This is the code that i am using to load the shared libary:

```
File stockfish = new File(getApplication().getApplicationInfo().nativeLibraryDir + "/lib_stockfish_sixten.so");
        try {
            engineProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(stockfish.getPath());
            processReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(engineProcess.getInputStream()));
            processWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(engineProcess.getOutputStream());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.println(Log.INFO, "Stockfish", "Error while loading Stockfish");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I was expecting that after i started stockfish i can send him the command `isready` but nothing happen and i get this error. (And i also geting this error when i dont send this command)